# The question/questions which one is this? or which ones are these?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, singular

Consider a sentence below.

> The question/questions "which one is this?" or "which ones are these?" force an identifying response.

I am confused. Should I use "the question" or "the questions?"

Since there are two questions, it should be plural, but both questions are separated by the conjunction "but".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is a bit off for either.  I believe you want...

> The **questions** "which one is this?" **and** "which ones are these?" force an identifying response.

'Questions' is plural, and allows both sides to be asked.  This is the syntax you're wanting since you're making a claim about both questions and not a single one.

Also, if you're asking a question inside a sentence, use quotation marks to separate the question from the containing sentence.